# NSView layout method not called after setNeedsLayout:YES

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, layout, nsview

As of OSX 10.7 if you wish to perform a manual layout of a NSView you should do so by overriding the `layout` method and whenever you wish to schedule a call to this method you simply do:

```
[myView setNeedsLayout:YES]
```

I am very familiar with this pattern in iOS however on OSX it does not seem to work. I have created a custom NSView and implemented `layout` but it seems that it never gets called. Ever. Not after adding subviews, not after calling `setNeedsLayout:YES`, not ever and I don't know why. I can manually call `layout` and things work as expected but the docs say never to do this.

From Xcode:

```
- (void)layout
Override this method if your custom view needs to perform custom
layout not expressible using the constraint-based layout system. In
this case you are responsible for calling setNeedsLayout: when
something that impacts your custom layout changes.
```

From the online docs:

> You should only override layout only if you want to do custom layout.
>   If you do, then you also need to invoke setNeedsLayout: when something
>   that feeds into your custom layout changes.

Link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631-CH1-SW14

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a link to a sample Xcode project that illustrates the problem [LayoutTest.zip](http://cl.ly/0g0O1D3V0U2J)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable autolayout.  If you're using a xib file (and you should be, no commando!) you can check the autolayout checkbox in the Interface Builder Document part of the file inspector.

In code: 
    [myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]

In your sample project, you have no constraints.  The view won't call layout without any constraints.

```
NSView *aView = self.window.contentView;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary=NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aView, complexView);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[aView]-[complexView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in constraints) {
    [complexView addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

Comment: I am not using IB. It is easier, and much more flexible IMO to do layout calculations by hand. I've been doing it this way in iOS for years without problem. OSX seems to be a different beast.

Comment: @nick as you say in your question: "Any help is much appreciated" - and Derek's "suggestion" to use IB is excellent advice!

Comment: If you want to write it in code, or if you want different sets of your code out of springs and struts, you can conditionally set an NSView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, however my question is regarding why the layout method is not being called when the docs clearly state that it should be invoked after setNeedsLayout:YES.

Comment: The docs aren't precise.  All of that code is specific to auto layout.  Auto layout didn't exist until 10.7 and isn't the norm for most vet Cocoa coders.  -layout is ONLY called if auto layout is turned on for that view.  In your view, call [myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES].

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints actually defaults to YES according to the docs. Either way changing this value to YES or NO does not seem to call the layout method via setNeedsLayout:YES.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any xib files in your project at all?  If so, are you setting your auto layout inside -initWithFrame: AND -awakeFromNib?  What may be happening is that your init methods may not be getting called as the initial xib file is loaded.

Comment: Yes I do have other xibs but I have verified that my init method is being called with breakpoints. I have updated the question to include a sample Xcode project that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. This answer does work. Seems weird that I have to add an _autolayout_ constraint in order to perform a _manual_ layout.

Comment: That's because autolayout is for automatic layouts, ie constraints.  You're supposed to be using -layout to handle broken constraints or such at runtime.